# Python opencv erase watermark from image cannot clean watermark

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to erase watermark from an image. I used Opencv but its giving image without cleaning

My code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

img = cv2.imread(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/" + "test.jpg")

alpha = 2.0
beta = -160

new = alpha * img + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/" + "cleaned.png", new)
```

I want to Erase "OLX" Watermark.

[My Image to Erase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkC9s.jpg)

How i can do that ?

Comment: your img variable seems to be not getting initialized correctly

Comment: Yes that's worked. but cleaned image still have watermark